# React/Redux - list not updating after a list item is editted

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I Have a list of objects being displayed in a table.
When an item in the list is edited, the updated item  is not displayed unless I refresh the page.

REDUCER FOR LIST

```
export const eaCodesReducer = (state = initialState.eaCodes, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_EA_CODES": {
            return {
                ...state,
                eaCodes: action.payload
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

REDUCER FOR SINGLE ITEM

```
export const eaSingleEaCodeReducer = (state = initialState.eaCode, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_EA_CODE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                eaCode: action.payload
            }
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

How do I then tell it to update the eaCodes list to incorporate the single item change?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const eaSingleEaCodeReducer = (state = initialState.eaCode, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_EA_CODE": {
            return {
                ...state,
                eaCode: action.payload,
                eaCodes: [...state.eaCodes, action.payload]
            }
        }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `eaCodesReducer` should return an array instead of an object. So the new state is always the previous items in the array along with the new one and you should map over this piece of state in your component which is bound to your store. The update in the table should reflect automatically when this particular piece of state is updated in your store.

```
                              // this should be an array also
export const eaCodesReducer = (state = initialState.eaCodes, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "GET_EA_CODES": {
          // should be an array
          return [
              ...state,
              action.payload
          ]
      }
      default: {
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

@D10S had the right idea, but resulted in the app crashing. Instead of adding the extra reducer - i updated the action to call the reducer if the initial put request is successful:

```
export const updateEnforcementActionCode = (id, updateTypeObj) => {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.put(`/api/enforcementactions/codes/${id}`, updateTypeObj)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_EA_CODE", payload: res.data })
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    return axios.get('/api/enforcementactions/codes')
                        .then(res => {
                            dispatch({ type: "GET_EA_CODES", payload: res.data })
                        })
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                dispatch({ type: "GET_ERRORS", payload: err.response.message })
            })
    }
}
```

This does seem a little redundant. If anyone has a suggestion to make this slicker I'm open.